# ASP.NET MVC Deployment Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, deployment

I have deployed my application to a server running IIS6 using the method which invloves changing the routes to:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

And adding a handler in IIS for .mvc extentions. This is working fine for the most part until I add the [Authorize] attribute to HomeController class.

This ends up in the app trying to redirect the user to the logon page which is what I expect however the logon page URL is shown as http://server/virtualdir/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fvirtualdir%2fDefault.aspx

This is causing a problem as no .mvc extension is being added to the Account controller part of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by changing the following in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account.mvc/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your question, but from my experience it worked just fine to deploy an application with the new routing features just as it is to IIS6 and add a wildcard mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll. Then you can use any URL you want, and nobody will notice when you change to a newer version in the future.

Yes, static file handling is theoretically less efficient this way, but you will need really a lot of traffic to notice anything. And if you really get a lot of traffic, you still could and even should move all your static files to a another domain/subdomain (or even a CDN) anyway, like [stackoverflow.com does](http://sstatic.net/). It can still point to the same server, you just use different IIS settings for this subdomain site. But with e. g. just a few thousand visitors per day you don't even have to think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i did see a mention of the option to use wilcard mappings, i will look into it further.